# Python Socket Programming Server and multiple clients failure of storing data

Tags: python, sockets

I am currently working on a simple school project on game server. I have one conceptual problem for dealing with the modified data in the TCPserver.

I have created a simple program for the issues. The clients will first type a number and the number will send to the server. This number will be processed in the server by adding 1 and the server will send the modified number back to clients. In addition, the modified number will also save to the `totalNum`, which store all the sum of clients modified number.

I expect the server will "store" the clients number. For instance, when client A send number 5, the `totalNum` would be 6. After that, when client B send number 8, client A data should still maintain in the sever, I expect the `totalNum` to be 6+9 = 15.

Server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import threading

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client

    def run(self):
        connectionSocket, addr = self.client    

        totalNum = 0

        number = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        newNumber = number.decode()
        newNumber = int(newNumber)
        editedNumber = newNumber + 1
        #add the edited number to the totalNum in the server
        totalNum = editedNumber + totalNum
        print (totalNum)
        #change back to str for sending
        editedNumber = str(editedNumber)
        connectionSocket.send(editedNumber.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()

class ServerMain:
    def server_run(self):  
        serverPort = 12000
        serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind( ("", serverPort) )
        serverSocket.listen(5)
        print("The server is ready to receive")
        while True:
            client = serverSocket.accept()
            t = ServerThread(client)
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ServerMain()
    server.server_run()
```

Client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serverName = "localhost"

serverPort = 12000

clientSocket.connect( (serverName, serverPort) )

# Get input for sending
number = input("Input a number:")

clientSocket.send(number.encode())

modifiednumber = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print("From Server:", modifiednumber.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

updated server code(changing the `totalNum` to class variable):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import threading

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    totalNum = 0
    def __init__(self, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client

    def run(self):
        connectionSocket, addr = self.client   

        number = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        newNumber = number.decode()
        newNumber = int(newNumber)
        editedNumber = newNumber + 1
        #add the edited number to the totalNum in the server
        self.totalNum = editedNumber + self.totalNum
        print (self.totalNum)
        #change back to str for sending
        editedNumber = str(editedNumber)
        connectionSocket.send(editedNumber.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()

class ServerMain:
    def server_run(self):  
        serverPort = 12000
        serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind( ("", serverPort) )
        serverSocket.listen(5)
        print("The server is ready to receive")
        while True:
            client = serverSocket.accept()
            t = ServerThread(client)
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ServerMain()
    server.server_run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre pretty close. move `totalNum = 0` to be a class level variable, i.e.

```
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    totalNum = 0
    def __init__(self, client):
```

and anywhere you use `totalNum` use it as `ServerThread.totalNum`

The problem was that you had totalNum as a scoped variable so it would get lost every time you finished `run()`. the issue arises if we made `totalNum` an instance variable. when `run()` ends the thread ends and the value gets lost again! by making it a class variable its always there and always shared. you can also access it from outside the class with `ServerThread.totalNum`

Comment: The same issues still exists. I have moved the `totalNum` to the class level variable. I run the server program first, and I also run two client program and type the number. The `totalNum` did not add the first client number. I believe your approach is correct and I guess I may did something wrong when I test the program.

Comment: @Dario please update the question with the new server code (just add it to the end)

Comment: The updated code is attached in the end. In my program, I would like to ask whenever when each client end their TCP connection with the server, the server data should suppose keep the latest updated data?

Comment: @Dario I accidently wrote `self` instead of `ServerThread`. i've updated the answer, you want to use `ServerThread.totalNum` for access instead of `self.totalNum`. As to your question, yes the server will maintain the number.